# Real-time deduplication strategy for relational DB

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb, deadlock, concurrency

I have a `messages` table with some fields like `id`, `version`, `timestamp`

I'm trying to insert and retrieve messages with real-time deduplication logic, implemented in stored procedures.

- On insert, if a message with given `id` already exists in the table, I invoke a complex deduplication logic (a number of IF/ELSE statements) and then update messages's `version`, `timestamp`, etc. Otherwise I insert a new row.
- On retrieve, I search for the oldest message and not just select it, but also update a few fields (changing `state`, setting `transient_token`, etc)

The problem is, **it does not work as fast as I need**: ~ 200 rps on insert and the same on retrieve

Separately my stored procedures work good, but when I execute both of them concurrently, they start fighting for locks under load > 30 rps, performance dramatically decreases and deadlocks appear periodically

**Are there some best practices to solve my problem?** I feel that the whole approach sucks, not my concrete implementation.

May be I should use some temp buffer table for all incoming messages and perform dedup logic afterwords? I would appreciate any ideas.

* I can't use nosql DB in my case (management decision), I need to gain max performance with Mysql/MariaDb

Comment: How many procedures? How many inserts/updates per execution? 1?

Comment: @StevenHibble 2 procedures (fitst for insert, second for retrieve), both of them perform 1 select and then 1 update/insert

Comment: Can you provide a snippet or sample for each?

Answer (score 1):

Good news. There is a SQL command usually called MERGE or UPSERT that basically does this.

See this page for more information:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

You probably want something like:

```
INSERT INTO messasges (id,version,timestamp) VALUES (1123,1,1/1/2017)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE version=2;
```

Comment: Unfortunately the deduplication logic is too complex for that, it's like 100 LOC of ugly if/else business logic right now (based on a messages's fields)

Comment: OK, please give a representative example if you want a useful answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Gather 100 records into a tmp table, then batch process them.  In the batching, see it you can do a single `SELECT` followed by perhaps one batch `INSERT` of some subset and another batch `UPDATE` of the others.  Or process until you can do all of them in a single IODKU.

See [*High speed ingestion*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/data-warehousing-high-speed-ingestion/) , especially the section on 'Normalization'; it discusses how to do a similar batching.